# Recover key from repeating-xor encryption

Tags: encryption, xor

Let's say that we have a set consisting of many strings encrypted with the same key by a xor cypher, moreover they are the same length as the key, both the key and the original strings might contain only small english letters and the space char.

We have encryption function E(k,m)=k⊕m and decryption D(k,c)=k⊕c, which means that m1⊕m2=c1⊕c2. Based on that I know that we can recover parts of the key used to encrypt the strings, for example:
In binary the ascii value of space is 00100000 and the lowercase letters start with 011. Knowing that m1⊕m2 has the first three bits of 010, we know, that one of the characters is a space. Then we can check m2⊕m3 and, for example, the first pair has a space and the second one does not, then we know that the space is m1, and we can calculate the part of the key used to encrypt it.

If the key has 64 bytes then we managed to recover 1/64 of the full key. However this method only works if one of the strings has a space on that byte, is there a way in which I can use the information stored in the strings to be able to semi-consistently recover some parts of the key? We are avoiding using brute force, i want to know if there is some way to find parts of the key that we are 100% certain of and are not simply guessing.

Comment: [This is so-called crib-dragging and two-time-pad, many-time-pad](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59/18298)